# SQL Searching - Two Columns Varying Values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Based on a poor database design beyond my control, I am now having to deal with something new (for me). I am hoping someone can assist me.

We have two columns in the database: "Column1" and "Column2"
Column1 can have a value of Breakfast/Lunch/Dinner. Column2 is free text and can contain many things.

How can I write a query where I can look for more than one specific value in Column1 and Column2 where both conditions must be true?

Example Code:

```
Select *
from TestDb
where (Column1 = 'Breakfast' and Column2 like '%banana%')
and (Column1 = 'Lunch' and Column2 like '%pizza%')
```

The expected result is that we find all subjects who had a banana for breakfast and pizza for lunch (which is why both conditions must be true). We don't want to find subject who just had a banana for breakfast or just pizza for lunch.

Comment: To make your question clearer, would you please provide sample data and expected result ?

Comment: You want an `OR` like in `(Column1 = '100' and Column2 like '%hello%') OR (Column1 = '150' and Column2 like '%goodbye%')`?

Comment: Requirements aren't clear. As @GMB said, could you post some examples of what you'd like to achieve?

Comment: No I don't want an OR operator. Both conditions must be true. To make the data clearer, let's assume 100 means breakfast and 150 means lunch. These two rows are tied to the same master ID but exist as two unique rows of data because there was not a column for breakfast or lunch on the master row. Therefore, we need to find both conditions true: breakfast = banana and lunch = pizza.

Comment: @ClassifiedMystery if you use AND you will get no rows.

Comment: Updated original post for clarification. Does this help?

Comment: Sounds like you want to use an `AND EXISTS` type logic. Really depends on what you're trying to achieve. I'll type up a quick example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to find out a single answer based on two different rows, then one approach is to check for one and then see if the other also exists. You haven't given a lot of info on your schema, so a simple example might be:

```
SELECT 'FOUND'
FROM TestDB a
WHERE a.Column1 = '100' and a.Column2 like '%hello%'
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM TestDB b
    WHERE b.Column1 = '150' and b.Column2 like '%goodbye%')
```

Obviously you can change `'FOUND'` for whatever relevant data  you'd like to return. If there's some kind of identifier you need to match on then you'd add that into the sub select, ie.: `AND b.Id = a.Id`.

If this doesn't give you what you want, I think you really need to give some examples in your question to clarify.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was missing. I've used this before but not in this scenario. Second pair of eyes is always helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Where column1 in (100,150) and (column2 like ‘%hello%’ or column2 like ‘%goodbye%’)

Comment: Sticky bit’s solution seems to better fit your example.

Answer (score 0):

You would seem to want something like this:

```
Select master_id
from TestDb
where (Column1 = '100' and Column2 like '%hello%') or
      (Column1 = '150' and Column2 like '%goodbye%')
group by master_id
having count(*) = 2;
```

This assumes that the rows are unique, so two rows do not match the same condition.

Answer (score 0):

may be we can use union ? I ran into similar thing way back, Union helped me. Please have a look, if it helps.

```
select * from table1 where column1 ='val1' and column2 ='val2'
  union
 select * from table1 where column1='val3' and column2 ='val4'
```

Joins are interesting, self joins are interesting too.

Comment: UNION suppresses duplicates which is an expensive operation. If you don;t need this use UNION ALL